# Is it possible to use paragraph tag inside h3

Tags: html, xhtml

Just wondering if it is possible to use the code in this way.

```
<h3>
<p>Some Text</p>
</h3>
```

While doing the w3c validation it is giving an error:

Element p not allowed as child of element h3 in this context.

Comment: You got a pretty clear (validation) error message...

Comment: Thanks.So I am allowed to do other way round.

Comment: Nope. `<p>`'s permitted content is the `Phrasing content`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) for details.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't (nor does it make sense to divide a heading into paragraphs).

You cannot have a heading inside a paragraph either (for similar reasons).

Answer (score 0):

w3-video.com has a section called "Place in page" for each HTML5 element
and you can see which elements can be nested within others

for example, here's the list for the p element

http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/p/html5_p_tag_nested.php